# Attribute about not allowed on element article at this point

Tags: entities, nodes, users

While i checked the markup of my drupal-7 site in http://validator.w3.org/check
it shows me a error:

> error Details:
>
> Attribute about not allowed on element article at this point.

I have checked my markup as well as all the functionality that are running properly. Why i am getting this error?

Comment: Related (if not a duplicate): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72390/is-drupal-following-w3c-standards/72393#72393

Comment: This is a problem with HTML. Version you are using does not allow for syntax you used at this point. The fact that it looks good and works good is not even near enough to make page valid. But pure HTML discussion is, as far as I understand, supposed to happen on stackoverflow.com, and problems with validator and certification on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: To expand slightly on the previous comment, if you are using a non-custom Drupal theme (i.e. premium or contrib), I would suggest it might belong here or in the issue queue for that theme. However, you have not mentioned this so as @Mołot said, this does run the risk of being off topic. Perhaps you coul expand the question to say whether you are using a custom theme, base theme or contrib/premium theme.

Comment: I am using a sub theme of bootstrap theme.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a markup error *somewhere* whereby you have an `<article>` tag with an `about` attribute (i.e. `<article class="my-class" about="blah">`).

I would imagine the site is working fine as the attribute will just be ignored if it's not applicable, so I'd find the page and line from the validator error and double check your markup.

You could also try running it past the newer HTML5 W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/nu/ just in case.

Comment: Yes it is rendering from the node.tpl.php from this

Comment: Could you clarify?  That comment doesn't make sense to me.